# My app crashes android studio when no value is plugged in by User

Tags: android, crash, try-catch

I'm trying to use try/catch method to prevent the app from crashing whenever there is no value provided by the user and even with this try catch, it still says error.

Thank you in advance to those kind souls who will reply

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

public void btnSubmit_OnClick(View view) {

    try {
        double num = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());

    }catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (num >= 6.5 && num < 14) {

            textView.setText("You may have Diabetes or if you are already diagnosed, have Uncontrolled Diabetes. However, I still find it best that you contact your attending physician for proper assessment. Thank you.");


        } else if (num >= 14){
            textView.setText("This is the highest level the application can read. Please contact your attending physician as either there is an error or you are suffering from a condition that warrants immediate referral. Thank you.");
```

Comment: Save us a little guess work and post your logcat with the error message.

Comment: For future reference you must know that a line of code like this :: `Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());` is not really easy to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare num outside the try-catch.

```
double num=0.0;
try {
    num = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
}catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

if (num >= 6.5 && num < 14) {

     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather check if when the user pressed the button the EditText is empty or not.

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

public void btnSubmit_OnClick(View view) {

if (editText.getText().toString() != null) {
    double num = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());

} else {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Fill in the field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
}

if (num >= 6.5 && num < 14) {
...
```